# Random Number Array/ minimum

Tags: c++, random, visual-c++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int minimum(int zahlen[])
{
 int minimum;
 int o = 0;
 bool prüf = false;
 while (true)
 {
     for (int p = 0; p < 20; p++)
     {
         if (o == zahlen[p])
         {
             minimum = zahlen[p];
             prüf = true;
         }
     }
     if (prüf == true)
     {
         break;
     }
     o++;
 }
 return minimum;
}

void main()
{
 srand(clock());
 int array[20];
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
     array[i] = rand();
 }

 //Minimum
 cout << "Die kleinste Zufallszahl die erstellt wurde ist die: " << minimum(array) << endl;

 system("PAUSE");
}
```

Hi, 
I have to create a 20 numbers long random array and check for the smallest number.
I know my code is probably not the best method to use for this problem but I am just always getting 371, 374, 202 or 208 as result. Never something else.
Is there a problem I don't see?

Comment: Did you use a debugger? Random input is not good for debugging. Try to find the minimum in a known array and only if this works try random input.

Comment: To get the smallest number in your array, you need only one loop that iterates over the array, once. Start by setting "current minimum value" to a very large value (e.g. `INT_MAX`), then compare it against every element in the array one by one. If the element in the array is smaller than the "current minimum value", then that becomes the new "current minimum value". After the loop finishes, return the "current minimum value" as it is the smallest value in the array.

Comment: When I am just giving out the "random" array they are differnet from another but not really random. Because every third or fourth time I am getting an array which i already had. So I am guessing there is a problem with my way of defining random numbers.

Comment: @idclev 463035818 Yes. I am using the local debugger from Visual Studio

Comment: @Some programmer dude Oh right. That's a good idea. Ill try that. But the problem that my numbers arent really random still remains :(

Comment: If the array doesn't contain any `0` you return an uninitialized value.

Comment: Note that `rand()` provides very large numbers. Is it what you want?

Comment: @Damien Yes. I want it to work with whatever number. 
The weird thing now is that with using rand(time(NULL)) instead of rand(clock()) it seems to work

Comment: The [`clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) function isn't supposed to get the "current time", that's what the [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function does.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely has to do with your use of clock(). According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock), clock() does not give you the current time. It gives you the time since your program started. So everytime you run this program, it takes roughly the same time for it to call clock(), meaning that the random seed is always about the same. To get the actual current world time, use [std::chrono::system_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) instead.

Also, an easier way of finding the minimum is this.

```
int minimum(int _randomNumbers[], int _arraySize)
{
    int minimum = _randomNumbers[0]; // By default, let's assume the element 0 has the smallest number.

    // Note that in this loop, i starts from 1, since there's no need to compare with element 0.
    for (int i = 1; i < _arraySize; ++i)
    {
        if (_randomNumbers[i] < minimum)
        {
            minimum = _randomNumbers[i];
        }
    }

    return minimum;
}
```